# Single post content not showing up

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have updated my wordpress and now my wordpress single posts are not showing. Header and post title are showing up but post title and sidebar are missing.

When I switch to some other theme everything works fine, but with my theme there is a problem. I tried to manually reinstall sigle.php of the theme but nothing changed. I tried changing permalinks structure, deleting all inactive plugins and turning off and on all active plugins but still nothing changed.

I am using a Sharp Magazine theme from Gabfire. Here is an example: http://www.turizamiputovanja.com/nis-dobija-novi-hotel-u-centru-grada/.

Here is my single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    /* post template defined on custom fields? */
    $post_layout = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gabfire_post_template', true); 

    /* Any subtitle entered to post? */
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subtitle', true);
     ?>

    <?php /* Post lead */ ?>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="post-lead">
                <p class="post-category"><?php the_category(' &middot; '); ?></p>
                <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p class="post-datecomment"> 
                    <?php
                    $authorlink = '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )).'">'.  get_the_author() . '</a>';
                    printf(esc_attr__('%2$s Autor: %1$s','gabfire'), $authorlink, get_the_date());
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    /* get the number of comments */
                     $num_comments = get_comments_number();
                     if ( comments_open() ){
                          if($num_comments == 0){  $comments = __('Nema komentara', 'gabfire');  }
                          elseif($num_comments > 1){ $comments = $num_comments. __(' Komentara', 'gabfire'); }
                          else{ $comments = __('1 komentar', 'gabfire'); }
                     }
                     echo '<span class="commentnr">' . $comments . '</span>';
                    ?>
                </p>

                <?php 
                if (($subtitle != '') && (($post_layout == 'bigpicture') or ($post_layout == 'fullwidth'))) { 
                    echo "<p class='subtitle postlead_subtitle'>$subtitle</p>"; }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php 
    /* Call user defined post template */ 
    if ($post_layout == 'bigpicture') {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'bigpicture' );

    } elseif ($post_layout == 'fullwidth') {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'fullwidth' );

    } elseif ($post_layout == 'leftsidebar') {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'leftsidebar' );

    } else {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'default' );   
    }
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have red all the similiar questions and answers here but none seems to be helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `the_content()` is being called outside the while loop - might be worth looking into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*the_content()* should be inside the loop as this is actually content of your post.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

/* post template defined on custom fields? */
$post_layout = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gabfire_post_template', true);

/* Any subtitle entered to post? */
$subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subtitle', true);
?>

<?php /* Post lead */ ?>
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="post-lead">
      <p class="post-category"><?php the_category(' &middot; '); ?></p>
      <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <p class="post-datecomment">
        <?php
        $authorlink = '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )).'">'.  get_the_author() . '</a>';
        printf(esc_attr__('%2$s Autor: %1$s','gabfire'), $authorlink, get_the_date());
        ?>
        <?php
        /* get the number of comments */
        $num_comments = get_comments_number();
        if ( comments_open() ){
          if($num_comments == 0){  $comments = __('Nema komentara', 'gabfire');  }
          elseif($num_comments > 1){ $comments = $num_comments. __(' Komentara', 'gabfire'); }
          else{ $comments = __('1 komentar', 'gabfire'); }
        }
        echo '<span class="commentnr">' . $comments . '</span>';
        ?>
      </p>

      <?php
      if (($subtitle != '') && (($post_layout == 'bigpicture') or ($post_layout == 'fullwidth'))) {
        echo "<p class='subtitle postlead_subtitle'>$subtitle</p>"; }
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

<?php
/* Call user defined post template */
/*if ($post_layout == 'bigpicture') {
get_template_part( 'single', 'bigpicture' );

} elseif ($post_layout == 'fullwidth') {
get_template_part( 'single', 'fullwidth' );

} elseif ($post_layout == 'leftsidebar') {
get_template_part( 'single', 'leftsidebar' );

} else {
get_template_part( 'single', 'default' );
} */
?>

<?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

*the_template_part* is loading *single-default.php* which is weird, because *single-default.php* contains another loop? This file structure is inappropriate, take a look on twentysixteen theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the single post content template.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

            if ( is_singular( 'attachment' ) ) {
                // Parent post navigation.
                the_post_navigation( array(
                    'prev_text' => _x( '<span class="meta-nav">Published in</span><span class="post-title">%title</span>', 'Parent post link', 'twentysixteen' ),
                ) );
            } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                the_post_navigation( array(
                    'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                        '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                        '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                    'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                        '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                        '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                ) );
            }

            // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Look at *get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );* They cut off the content stuff to other file *template-parts/content-single*. It is better in many ways fe. managment, version control.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I copied the code you send me and now post content appears, but the title appears under the post content (between author bio and adsense, you can see it here http://www.turizamiputovanja.com/nis-dobija-novi-hotel-u-centru-grada/. And sidebar is still missing. :/ How can I solve that? Please note that I do not have coding skills.

Comment: I edit the code, try it now, but all I do is just guessing, because Wordpress themes can vary a lot.

Comment: Now title appears above post content which is ok, but the sidebar also appears above all that (title and content), on the top of the page. Sidebar should appear on the right side, alongside with post content. Can you guess what can I change in order to do that? Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Try the new version in the post if it works please accept the answer.

Comment: I have just saw that since our last changes comments dont show up under the posts. Any idea how to fix that? Sorry for bothering :(, thanks!